# How can I sum a list of tuples in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is a super simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer. Say I have a list of tuples in Haskell,

```
myList = [("foo", 2), ("bar", 4), ("foo", 6), ("bar", 1)]
```

and I want to group them by their first elements and sum them on their second, how would I do that?

This example would output `[("foo", 8), ("bar", 5)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It heavily depends on whether your key (the first element in your tuple) is `Ord` or only `Eq`. If its only in `Eq`, then a [`partition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition)-based approach is fine:

```
import Data.List (partition)

sumByKey :: (Eq k, Num v) => [(k, v)] -> [(k, v)]
sumByKey []         = []
sumByKey ((k,v):xs) = (k,v + sum vs) : sumByKey bs
  where
    vs       = map snd ks
    (ks, bs) = partition ((k ==) . fst) xs
```

However, if you have `Ord` at hand and are fine with external dependencies, then [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) can make the code a lot easier:

```
import Data.Map.Strict

sumByKey :: (Ord k, Num v) => [(k, v)] -> [(k, v)]
sumByKey = toList . fromListWith (+)
```